# Intval and (int) outputs zero

Tags: php, arrays, int

I did search stackoverflow and other places to solve my problem but none of them could not help me solve it.

Inside my while loop the print_r() of $myvariable outputs the following array:

```
Array
 (
[1] => 0000890233330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b3165721010000000000
 )

Array
(
[1] => 00008a0233330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d5165721000000000000
)

Array
(
[1] => 00008b023333000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000109175721000000000000
)

Array
(
[1] => 00008f0233340000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ad185721000000000000
)

Array
(
[1] => 00009002333500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018d195721000000000000
)
```

I use the following code to take out

```
       $id = substr($myvariable[1], 6, 8);
       $cid = hex2bin($id);
       $rid =  intval(str_replace("\0", '', $cid));
```

in a shorter way:

```
$rid = intval( str_replace("\0", '', hex2bin( substr($myvariable[1], 6, 8) ) ) );
```

I am expecting to get integer 33 for all the 5 arrays except the last 2 which are 34 and 35. But I am getting zero(0). Without using the `intval()`, it is ok. I am testing with `(int)` and I got the same zero(0). So I end up without using `intval`/`(int)`. Though the output is a real number to my eyes, yet I would really appreciate if you could help me convert these to what php would understand them as real integer. Thanks.

Comment: Open a manual and read `Caution This function does NOT convert a hexadecimal number to a binary number. This can be done using the base_convert() function.`

Comment: If you really intended to create binary data not a base 2 string, also note that a 3-digit hex string ought to be padded to 4 before converting to 2 bytes: 5.4.4 A warning is thrown if the input string is of odd length. In PHP 5.4.0 the string was silently accepted, but the last byte was truncated.

Comment: @Dave S, I am using php 7.1.1 and 7.1.5. Could there be any issue with your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, mixed up my string libraries and was thinking [6]...[8] not [6]...[13].  See Barmar's answer below for exactly why your code fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this step by step:

```
$id = "02333300";
$cid = hex2bin($id);
```

Now `$cid` contains the following 4 characters:

```
\02
3
3
\0
```

Then we remove the `\0` character, so it contains:

```
\02
3
3
```

When we call `intval($cid)`, it start parsing the string, stopping when it gets to the first character that isn't a digit. In this case, that's the first character, because it's `\02`. Since it hasn't read any digits, it returns `0`.

You need to change your code to remove any non-printing characters before calling `intval()`.

```
$rid = preg_replace('/[\0-\31]/', '', $cid);
```

should do it.